# Wait until file descriptor is not readable anymore without busy loop

Tags: c, linux, select, io, epoll

Waiting for a file descriptor to become readable is very simple:

```
struct pollfd f;
signed result;

f.fd = a_file_descriptor_a_pipe_in_my_case;
f.events = POLLIN | POLLERR | POLLHUP;

result = poll(&f, 1, timeout_in_millis);
if (result < 0) {
    if (errno == EINTR) {
        // try again
    } else {
        // report error
    }
} else if (result == 0) {
    // timeout
} else {
    fd_is_readable = (f.revents & POLLIN) != 0;
    fd_has_an_error = (f.revents & POLLERR) != 0;
    fd_is_not_valid = (f.revents & POLLNVAL) != 0;
    other_end_of_the_pipe_was_closed = (f.revents & EPOLLHUP) != 0;
}
```

But how do I wait for a file descriptor to become NOT READABLE, i.e. empty, without a busy loop? My current approach is to sleep for some milliseconds, but that is not my favorite solution.

Comment: How would it become unreadable without reading from it
?

Comment: @Max, the FD is shared with another processes.

Comment: In this case, you might want to have the other process tell you "I have just emptied this fd" using IPC.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no good way to *wait* for an FD to stop being readable, and it's unclear what benefit you hope to gain from doing so.  You can, of course, try to *consume* the data available from a given FD until no more is available.  If you're relying on another thread or process to consume the data then you could consider implementing an explicit signal, maybe via a pipe or a semaphore.

Comment: @tofro, yes, that would be the optimal solution, because an empty pipe does not mean that all data was already processed. But I'm still curious if you can get `select`, `poll` or `epoll` to tell you if a file descriptor is empty.

Comment: All of the system interfaces you mention wait for FDs to become *ready* in one way or another.  You're looking for the opposite: waiting for an FD to become *un*ready.  These particular interfaces do not provide for that.  I am unaware of any that do, but I'm not quite prepared to deny that there are any.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no direct way to do such things as sending an "isEmpty" signal or flag to `select` or `poll` when a file descriptor has *nothing* to read.

After all, the use case of any fd and the `select` mechanism is to *transfer* data, and not to *not transfer data*... So you could argue that this is not the job of this system routines.

The only fact that is transported to `select`is when the file descriptor is *no longer existing*, which is a special case of "no data available" - I don't think that covers your use case, though.

Either you turn the logic around and make sure data *is always available* by having the producer send some sort of *heartbeat* over the descriptor that can be checked for and, for example, resets a timer, or you have the data consumers send a signal (or other IPC message) to the monitoring process that signals "I have just emptied that fd" to the monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [man read](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read) it says `read` returns `0` which basically means `end of file` and that means there are no more data to read from the fd.
As for without using a loop you could try the event-based approach where you assign a callback function to an event and that function will get called when the event occurs. ([link](https://linux.die.net/man/2/read))

Also, not sure with regular Linux but for OpenWrt I use their `ustream` library which allows you to stream data through a pipe and that would make your job a lot easier.